# How can I read an SNMP MIB file in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, snmp

How to read a MIB file(.Mib file) using c#.net

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asn.1) parser, or use an off-the-shelf component. I use [NetToolWorks](http://www.nettoolworks.com/), and am happy with it.

If you do want to roll your own, here's some [sample code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/asn1editor.aspx) to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you need, you have multiple choices.

ASN.1 parsers can be used to parse details. But if you just need to know the OID for objects, #SNMP Suite already has a basic MIB parser/compiler available via both its library (SharpSnmpLib.Mib namespace) and its GUI tool (MIB Compiler and Browser).

[https://sharpsnmp.com](http://sharpsnmp.com)

As far as I know, Net-SNMP only has a MIB to C tool.